# Ethernet shows disconnected yet cable plugged in

Tags: networking, 16.04, dell, ethernet

I have a Latitude E7240. Network cable is plugged in but Ethernet Network disconnected. Have tried all kinds of things with blacklisting, driver search, work off the install USB but to no avail.

Here are characteristics of my system and certain log messages.

Thank you for any help.
muixca

> lspci | egrep -i 'network|ethernet'

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
```

> lshw -C network

```
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: f0:1f:af:44:df:d0
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.7-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e3c000-f7e3cfff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 73
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:9a:94:d5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

> cat /var/log/syslog | grep "eth" | tail -100

```
May 17 11:57:45 pi kernel: [    1.301756] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
May 17 11:57:45 pi kernel: [    1.301769] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) f0:1f:af:44:df:d0
May 17 11:57:45 pi kernel: [    1.301772] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
May 17 11:57:45 pi kernel: [    1.301795] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
May 17 11:57:45 pi kernel: [    1.302537] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
May 17 11:57:45 pi NetworkManager[716]: <info>  [1463479065.8244] Loaded device plugin: NMVethFactory (internal)
May 17 12:26:32 pi kernel: [    1.281566] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
May 17 12:26:32 pi kernel: [    1.281569] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) f0:1f:af:44:df:d0
May 17 12:26:32 pi kernel: [    1.281570] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
May 17 12:26:32 pi kernel: [    1.281593] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
May 17 12:26:32 pi kernel: [    1.282264] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
May 17 12:26:32 pi NetworkManager[685]: <info>  [1463480792.7346] Loaded device plugin: NMVethFactory (internal)
May 17 15:31:45 pi kernel: [    1.281609] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
May 17 15:31:45 pi kernel: [    1.281612] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) f0:1f:af:44:df:d0
May 17 15:31:45 pi kernel: [    1.281613] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
May 17 15:31:45 pi kernel: [    1.281638] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
May 17 15:31:45 pi kernel: [    1.282343] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
May 17 15:31:45 pi NetworkManager[715]: <info>  [1463491905.7807] Loaded device plugin: NMVethFactory (internal)
May 17 15:42:19 pi kernel: [    0.975770] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
May 17 15:42:19 pi kernel: [    0.975783] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) f0:1f:af:44:df:d0
May 17 15:42:19 pi kernel: [    0.975785] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
May 17 15:42:19 pi kernel: [    0.975809] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
May 17 15:42:19 pi kernel: [    0.976390] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
May 17 15:42:19 pi NetworkManager[704]: <info>  [1463492539.6124] Loaded device plugin: NMVethFactory (internal)
May 17 15:44:18 pi kernel: [    0.970795] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
May 17 15:44:18 pi kernel: [    0.970808] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) f0:1f:af:44:df:d0
May 17 15:44:18 pi kernel: [    0.970810] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
May 17 15:44:18 pi kernel: [    0.970834] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
May 17 15:44:18 pi kernel: [    0.971359] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
May 17 15:44:18 pi NetworkManager[697]: <info>  [1463492658.5978] Loaded device plugin: NMVethFactory (internal)
```

> contents of `/etc/networkmanager.conf` and `/etc/interfaces`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false


# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

> uname -a

```
Linux pi 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

updated output

**ethtool eno1**

```
Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

**lspci -v**

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I218-LM
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 43
    Memory at f7e00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=128K]
    Memory at f7e3c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f080 [disabled] [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Comment: is it a dsl connection ?

Comment: it's a VSAT 1/1 connection (don't know if that's catalogued as 'dsl')

Comment: ok if your ISP gave you an username and password than try creating a dsl connection. You can do it by selecting `Edit Connection` from network menu, and create new connection, select connection type as `dsl` and enter usename and password given by your ISP. Try this.

Comment: sorry... didn't work... thx for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on this line:

```
May 17 15:44:18 pi kernel: [    0.971359] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
```

your network card gets renamed to `eno1`, so using `ethtool eth0` will yield no results.  You need to use `ethtool eno1`

Use `lspci -v` .  This will show you what kernel module is handling your network card.  If there is no module listed, you need either a driver or possibly a kernel upgrade for your card to work.

Comment: thank you as well for your swift reply. I updated the question (up) with the requested info. Dunno how properly format it here. m~

Comment: i had upgraded the kernel and the driver is installed as far as i can see. i am inclined to conclude that my card is busted.